# Passing a parameter in ng-click function

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, input, this

I am trying to pass data to an API for the user e-mail subscription status as "Y"/"N".

In the controller code `console.log(a.checked)` is undefined. But in regular javascript a onclick event for the input element `type="checkbox"` has the `this.checked` to respond correspondingly as true or false. Why is it not happening here in AngularJS?

**My html code with angular directive ng-click:**

```
<label for="mail_sub">E-mail subscription</label>
<input id="mail_sub" type="checkbox" name=checkbox ng-click="mailsubscription(this)">
```

**Code of the controller:**

```
.controller("registerCtrl", function($scope, $state, userProcess) {
    $scope.mailsubscription = function(a) {
        console.log(a);
        console.log(a.checked); // console output is: "undefined"
        signupinfo = {};
        if (a.checked) {
            signupinfo.u_mail_subscription = 'Y';
        } else {
            signupinfo.u_mail_subscription = 'N';
        }
        console.log(signupinfo);

    };
    /*$scope.registerProcess = function(signupinfo){
                console.log(signupinfo);
                userProcess.signup(signupinfo).sucess(function(response){

                    if(response.status){


                    }
                })

            };*/
});
```

Comment: where are you specifying model for this input where is ng-model?

Answer (score 1):

There is no checked defined in your scope. You have do to something like this:

```
$scope.checked = false
$scope.mailsubscription = function () {
    $scope.checked = !$scope.checked;
    console.log($scope.checked)
};
```

Or you can use ngModel directive in your template

```
<input id="mail_sub" type="checkbox" name=checkbox ng-click="mailsubscription(this)" ngModel="checked">
```

If you go this way you dont need to toggle the variable checked by your self.